# Performing raster calculations along line feature or within polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I need to add a value to a dem file along a polyline feature or within a polygon.  How can I add 100 to the values of the raster cells intersected by my line feature or within my polygon feature.

I would like to know how to do this in QGIS, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using GDAL:

1. Create a mask from the resulting vector stuff (polyline feature or within a polygon)
   http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html
2. Synchronize the map area, the raster width of the mask with the config of the dem 
   http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html
3. Use gdal_calc.py with the mask condition to add 100 to your dem. 
   http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html